# TableView with CollectionView Cells and Top Cell Sticking to the Top

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am intersted in a layout very similar to the App Store app, the "Featured" tab. I think I can achieve this by having a `UITableView` whose cells are horizontal `CollectionViews`. So that part is not really my question. The part that I have a question is that the top row of this `UITableView` `scrolls` out of the `view` if you pan (drag) up on the screen but it stick to the top when you pan down. I would like to know how I can achieve that stickiness in one direction.

Comment: Make your top cell as section header or just make it as independent view above the table

Comment: It's a supplementary view inside the UICollectionView, which can be pinned by overriding the UICollectionViewFlowLayout. It's pretty hard to achieve, but that's how it's done in AppStore app by Apple.